# Error between install polka socket.io?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Error between install polka socket.io ?

```
npm init -y
npm i --save polka serve-static socket.io
```

[image]

source from : `https://scotch.io/@Youngestdev/build-a-simple-chatroom-with-socketio-and-polka`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named your project same as dependency you want to install (In package.json file, check "name" field).

see more [HERE](http://thisdavej.com/node-newbie-error-npm-refusing-to-install-package-as-a-dependency-of-itself/)

also, system giving error of NO SPACE LEFT.